# Missing capital cities (a puzzle of - - - - -)

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, geography

What you see below are two **ordered** sets of capital cities. There are 5 capital cities missing from each set and your task is to find them and then give me the final 10-letter word.

---

```
     —
```

- Jerevan
- Baku
- Sucre
- Sofia
- ... (5)
- Zagreb
- ... (4)
- Tallinn
- Addis Ababa
- Libreville
- Accra
- Berlin
- Budapest
- New Delhi
- Tehran
- Baghdad
- Maseru
- ... (7)
- Vilnius
- Lilongwe
- Amsterdam
- Niamey
- ... (5)
- Moscow
- Kigali
- Belgrade
- Bratislava
- Ljubljana
- ... (5)
- Damascus
- Dushanbe
- Caracas
- Sana'a

  ```
   |
  ```
- ... (7)
- Yaoundé
- ... (1)
- N'Djamena
- Paris
- ... (2)
- Rome
- ... (11)
- Bamako
- Mexico City
- Chisinau
- Lima
- ... (8)

Comment: Is the (5) between Ljubljana and Damascus definitely correct, or are you using something a little more 'historic' in that position?

Comment: i'm using [Wikipedia's list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals) sorted in alphabetical order of countries

Comment: @newQOpenWid I think there's a different Wiki page you would find more useful...

Comment: @Stiv Ah, silly mistake. The list I used for this puzzle included that one, so yes you're right.

Comment: @Prim3numbah Do you want to change the puzzle to account for that, or leave it as is? (It's answerable as is...)

Comment: oh, and I'm confused about the (1) and (2). Can there really be a capital city with *only one* letter in it?

Comment: @Stiv I think I'll leave it as it is. The idea was one number per missing capital. So you can  just post an answer with a notation that I made a mistake on that one.

Comment: Ready to go! Thanks for the lunchtime mental runaround, even if it didn't all quite go to plan (it happens!)...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The final 10-letter word is:

> **TRICOLOURS**

Find this by noticing that the two lists of capitals provided are...

> ...the capitals of countries with **horizontal tricolour flags** (headed by '-'), and the capitals of countries with **vertical tricolour flags** (headed by '|').
>
>  In both cases these are ordered alphabetically by the names of the countries. Thus we need to find the capital cities for the countries that would fit alphabetically into these slots, having the appropriate tricolour flag orientation.

This means our missing capitals are:

> Bogo[t]a (of Colombia)
>  Cai[r]o (of Egypt)
>  Tripol[i] (of Libya)
>  Asun[c]ion (of Paraguay)
>  Pret[o]ria (of South Africa, when using the 1928-1994 flag that appears in the list of tricolours on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tricolour), which I suspect the OP was referring to when creating this puzzle...)
>
>  and
>
>  Brusse[l]s (of Belgium)
>  [O]ttawa (of Canada)
>  D[u]blin (of Ireland)
>  Yamoussouk[r]o (of Ivory Coast)
>  Buchare[s]t (of Romania)

To get the final 10-letter answer, we must...

> ...use the numbers in brackets to help us extract the letters in that numbered position within the names of the capital cities (e.g. the 5th letter of Bogota is 't') and read them down the list. I have indicated these in the lists in the previous spoiler using square brackets. This gives us the appropriate answer, **TRICOLOURS**.
>
>  (And regarding the title, I expect the 5-letter word missing there is 'FLAGS'...)

Comment: Well done :) And you're correct regarding the missing word in the title. I should've seen that, It's one of the more easier (- - - - -) to recognize. I just followed the list without really looking closely at it.

Comment: @Prim3numbah For a while I had 'Madrid' in there - but I'm guessing Spain didn't count because it's not actually rot13(gev-pbybhe, fvapr gjb bs vgf guerr fgevcrf ner erq). This 'historical' possibility was the only one I could make fit to get the letter I needed for the appropriate answer!

Comment: Yes exactly, they use two of the same. Well spotted and nice job!

Comment: The wikipedia page notwithstanding, I would not consider the flag of Canada a "tricolor"; it only has two colors. Certainly, if Canada counts, so should Spain.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin That is a very good point... I think collectively we have good cause to get that Wikipedia page edited properly!

Comment: @JeffZeitlin You're right and I see now that there is another one aswell (Peru). That wikipedia list included some but excluded some other for some reason. But again, I should've looked more careful.

Comment: I should also note that looking at [this other wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallery_of_sovereign_state_flags) shows a number of sovereign state flags that are arguably tricolors within the apparent definition of the original wikipedia listing, but which were not included in the other page.